# Spring MVC 6: How to have different form submit buttons invoke different controller methods in multi-part form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've got a Spring MVC 6.20 page. It has a form with two submit buttons named "submit1" and "submit2". Depending on the pressed button, I need the controller to invoke the submit1() or submit2() controller methods.

```
   <form:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <button type="submit" name="submit1">Submit 1</button>
           <button type="submit" name="submit2">Submit 2</button>
       </form:form>
```

```
    @PostMapping(params = "submit1")
        public String submit1(HttpServletRequest request) {     
            return "submit1";
        }
        
    @PostMapping(params = "submit2")
        public String save2(HttpServletRequest request) {       
            return "submit2";
        }
```

It doesn't work with <form:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> but it works without enctype="multipart/form-data".
I tried replacing "params" with "headers" and it does not work. I get a 404 error on Tomcat.

Any help would be appreciated.